# What characters are NOT escaped with a mysqli prepared statement?

Tags: php, security, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to harden some of my PHP code and use mysqli prepared statements to better validate user input and prevent injection attacks.

I switched away from mysqli_real_escape_string [as it does not escape % and _](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). However, when I create my query as a mysqli prepared statement, the same flaw is still present. The query pulls a users salt value based on their username. I'd do something similar for passwords and other lookups.

Code:

```
$db = new sitedatalayer();

if ($stmt = $db->_conn->prepare("SELECT `salt` FROM admins WHERE `username` LIKE ? LIMIT 1")) {

  $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($salt);
  

  while ($stmt->fetch()) { 
    printf("%s\n", $salt);
  } 
    
  $stmt->close();    

}
    
else return false;
```

- Am I composing the statement correctly?
- If I am what other characters need to be examined? What other flaws are there?
- What is best practice for doing these types of selects?

Thanks,

Comment: Why a `LIKE` clause and not an exact comparison `=`?

Comment: Ignoring the LIKE-hating, as far as "injection" goes, escaping out of the var is impossible with bind variables (as long as you use them exclusively), so injecting other queries is prevented with use of mysqli. Others have covered the semantic issues on LIKE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`%` is not an inherently harmful character.

The question is: why are you using a `LIKE` in the first place? Are there **any** circumstances in which you wouldn't require an **exact** match for username?

The query should be simply:

```
SELECT `salt` FROM admins WHERE `username` = ? LIMIT 1
```

In that case, if I were to enter `%bsmith` my username would have to be (literally) "%bsmith" in order for you to find a match.

Comment: Thanks - I tried using an = sign earlier and my query didnt work. Must have had an error somewhere else. Works now.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing two different levels of evaluation here.

The `LIKE` operator takes a string and evaluates any `'%'` and `'_'` as placeholders.

The job of query parameters is it only to bring values (e.g. strings) *verbatim* to the database engine, so they cannot be mistaken for SQL code. They don't care how the `LIKE` operator makes special use of certain characters *within the string* they've just transported. Everything just works as designed here.

If you want exact matches, use the `=` operator in place of `LIKE`.

If you must use `LIKE` (even though your `LIMIT 1` indicates otherwise here), [escape the the special characters accordingly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) yourself beforehand.

Comment: If they are placed verbatim, then why use prepared statements and not just insert $username right into a string?

Comment: @barfoon: As I said, parameters work on the "SQL string literal" level. They make sure string literals do not break. `LIKE` works one abstraction level higher, because it interprets the string *contents* according to its own rules. Parameters play no part here anymore, all they do is making sure your SQL statement does not break.

Answer (score -1):

It is one who is using LIKE to match a username to blame, not escaping function.

And, just for your info: native **prepared statements do not escape anything**.

Comment: ADODB and PDO for PHP uses mysql_real_escape_string(),  if you don't believe me,  look at the code,  i have.   I should give you a -1,  but i think i have given you enough of 'em :p

Comment: Okay well i still care about incorrect statements `prepared statements do not escape anything.`

Comment: for the record i didn't give you the -1.

Answer (score -1):

These are the characters not escaping by  prepared statements     %  _   \