# How to upgrade from mysql_* to mysqli_*?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm currently using deprecated code to get data from users, as follows:

```
/* retrieve */
$lastName = $_POST['lastName']; 
$firstName = $_POST['firstName']; 
$examLevel=$_POST['level'];

/* connect */
$dbc=mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "passw") or die('Error connecting to MySQL server');
mysql_select_db("db") or die('Error selecting database.');

/* sanitize */
$lastName=mysql_real_escape_string($lastName);
$firstName=mysql_real_escape_string($firstName); 
$examLevel=mysql_real_escape_string($examLevel);


/* insert */
$query_personal = "INSERT INTO personal (LastName, FirstName) VALUES  ('$lastName', '$firstName')";

$query_exam = "INSERT INTO exam (Level, Centre, BackupCentre, etc.) VALUES ('$examLevel', '$centre', '$backup', 'etc')";
```

This is working but I keep coming across warnings about security and lack of support. There's a small rewrite to **connect** with mysqli instead of mysql but what about **mysqli_real_escape_string**? I've seen it used in examples but I've also seen advice to use prepared statements instead which don't use mysqli_real_escape_string.

And how would I use prepared statements to INSERT my data? I'm a bit at sea with this bit so far. For example, is parameter binding only for INSERTs and result binding only for SELECTs?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't get the code formatting right.

Comment: What's so hard about marking all the code and clicking on `{}`?

Comment: I wonder is that a record for being patronised here? 2min 35sec. I will try to get the hang of it!

Comment: Did you read the manual to learn about `mysqli_*` and implementing it? If not, [here you go](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: PDO's named parameters make binding placeholder values a lot easier to manage.

Comment: If you are switching then then PDO is better http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php. Learn it. Implement it and switch. There is not a simple definite way to switch from ``mysql`` to ``mysqli``.

Comment: Ok, the consensus seems to be for PDO! Thanks. That hashphp tutorial is great, Nick. Much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

```
/* connect */
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;db=test;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,"user", "passw", $opt);


/* insert */
$query = "INSERT INTO personal (LastName, FirstName) VALUES  (?, ?)";
$stmt  = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['lastName'],$_POST['firstName']));

$query = "INSERT INTO exam (Level, Centre, BackupCentre, etc) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 'etc')";
$stmt  = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array($_POST['level'], $centre, $backup));
```

Comment: Thank you, YCS! Now that I'm swotting up on PDO I'll study your answer carefully.

Answer (score 0):

see this pages for converting mysql into mysqli

[Converting_to_MySQLi](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Converting_to_MySQLi)

https://wikis.oracle.com/display/mysql/Converting+to+MySQLi

and see [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) manual that explain about `mysqli_real_escape_string` and Security problem and how to solve it.

php.net:

**Security: the default character set**

The character set must be set either at the server level, or with the API function [mysqli_set_charset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) for it to affect mysqli_real_escape_string(). See the concepts section on [character sets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php) for more information.

see this page for query for  [insert data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html)

see this page for [prepare data for inserting  to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710381/problems-in-inserting-data-using-safe-way-to-input-data-to-mysql-using-php)

and http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php